# ¿Como hacer un UPDATE de registros a 3 tablas relacionadas?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo tres tablas relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que debo hacer es editar la informacion de un curso por ejemplo la fecha de inicio y en la tabla cuotas editar la cantidad de cuotas, para posterior editar el numero de montos en la tabla detalle_cuota. Es hacer un update a las 3 tablas relacionadas, pero no se como manejar el update, supongo que es mediante los id_primary pero estoy algo perdido. Toda esos datos me los traigo en un form para luego editarlos, por ejemplo quiero cambiar la fecha de inicio que esta en: 26-08-2017 a 30-08-2017, editar la cantidad de cuotas del curso, tiene 4 cuotas ahora quiero ponerle 6 cuotas, y que segun esa cantidad de cuotas me actualize los montos en la tabla detalle_cuota, si estaban en 4 que ahora sean 6. Necesito orientacion por favor! Lo unico que se me ocurre es hacer 3 update y ir recuperando el id que actualiza en cada update, pero no se si funcione.

Answer (score 2):

Yo enfocaría la solución a 1 update, 1 delete y 1 insert. Me explico:

```
UPDATE cursos_abiertos SET inicio = '30-08-2017' WHERE id = <id_curso>
```

Luego eliminaría las cuotas que existan asociadas al curso, para luego replanificar los pagos (aquí asumo que tienes un `DELETE ON CASCADE` que limpiará la tabla `detalle_cuota`):

```
DELETE FROM cuotas c 
WHERE id_curso = <id_curso> 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM detalle_cuota WHERE id_curso = c.id_curso AND estado = 0)
```

Calculamos el monto total a replanificar

```
SELECT SUM(monto)/<nuevo numero de cuotas>
FROM detalle_cuota dc 
INNER JOIN cuotas c
ON c.id = dc.id_curso
WHERE c.id_curso = <id_curso>

INSERT INTO cuotas (...) VALUES (...),(...),(...) /* nuevas cuotas */

INSERT INTO detalle_cuotas (...,monto,...) VALUES (...,<monto por cuota>,...)
```

En resumen, tener un poco de cuidado relacionando los datos, pero mucho más robusto que actualizar IDs.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por responder Daniel, lo que no entiendo es lo que hace ese SELECT, si puedes explicarme por favor.

Comment: Hola Luis, pues de alguna forma tienes que calcular el monto pendiente que no ha sido pagado aun, el select pretende darte esa información... podrías hacerlo en un procedimiento almacenado o recuperar el resultado del select en php... el resultado corresponde a `<monto por cuota>`